# Difference between \xrightarrow and \overset\to

Tags: spacing, arrows, overset, xrightarrow

What is the difference between `\xrightarrow h` and `\overset h\to`?  The output seems to differ ever so slightly.  Is one to be preferred over the other?  Is one less likely to create unsightly gaps between lines because it is too tall?  (I know that `\xrightarrow` adjusts the length of the arrow to accomodate the length of what is being put above it, making it preferable to `\to` for long texts above the arrow.  My question is whether there is any reason to prefer one or the other in the specific situation of a short symbol over the arrow.)

Comment: `\xrightarrow` is extensible, in function of what is above the arrow (or under, with the optional argument).

Comment: Try `\xrightarrow{x\to0}` versus `\overset{x\to0}{\to}` to see the difference.

Comment: OK, yes, I know that `\xrightarrow` gets longer while `\to` does not.  I guess I was asking about other differences.  Will edit the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With a slim superscript, such as *i*, the result is almost identical; only the superscript is positioned slightly differently.

With *h* the difference is more sensible, because `\xrightarrow` extends the arrow a bit.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,color}

\begin{document}

\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{red}$A\overset{i}{\to}B$}$A\xrightarrow{i}B$

\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{red}$A\xrightarrow{i}B$}$A\overset{i}{\to}B$

\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{red}$A\overset{h}{\to}B$}$A\xrightarrow{h}B$

\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{red}$A\xrightarrow{h}B$}$A\overset{h}{\to}B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note, however, that the height of the superscript is the same.

If you need horizontal alignment across lines, say for `align` or `split`, then `\overset` might be preferable, provided the superscript doesn't clash with the arrow.

Side note: avoid input such as `\overset h\to`. It's awkward to read and much less clearer than `\overset{h}{\to}`.

Comment: "Awkward to read" is very much a matter of opinion, I think.  I find that blizzards of `{}`s in TeX make it harder to read, not easier.